How to Design a Dynamic API that Allows Clients to Specify Fields - Is This Approach Outdated?
Question:
I often work on Web API projects using .NET, and I find the idea of allowing clients to specify which data fields to retrieve—similar to GraphQL—quite intriguing. However, I haven't come across any libraries that support this in RESTful APIs. I'm wondering if this idea is considered outdated.
GET /api/User/?fields=name&fields=Email&populate[Role][fields]=name

And receive:
{
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        ...
        "role": {
            "name": "Admin"
          ...
        }
}

So, I created a simple .NET library to handle this. Contributions and feedback are welcome! GitHub: https://github.com/Authentic199/Population.NET.
I'd love to hear insights from those who've implemented similar APIs or considered dynamic field selection as part of their API design.
I tried searching for similar library but couldn't find any, so I look forward to everyone's opinion

Well - if GraphQL already does that - then why not just use it ?

Thank your answer! However, my company strictly uses RESTful APIs, so it's more of a job requirement, sir.

Hi, Welcome to SO.  You're question will be closed because: 1. Any answer will be opinion based and 2. It could be construed [whether intentionally or not] the main purpose of your question is to advertise your library.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
